# What's the difference between match method and the =~ operator?

Tags: ruby, match

Two expressions:

```
puts "String has vowels" if "This is a test".match(/[aeiou]/)
```

and

```
puts "String has vowels" if "This is a test" =~ /[aeiou]/
```

seem identical. Are they not? I did some testing below:

```
"This is a test" =~ /[aeiou]/
# => 2

"This is a test".match(/[aeiou]/)
# => MatchData "i"
```

So it seems like `=~` gives you the position of the first match and `match` method gives you the first character that matches. Is this correct? They both return `true` and so what's the difference here?

Comment: What do [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Regexp.html) say?

Comment: The question does not make much sense. As you noticed, the difference disappears when you embed them in a conditional, but that does not mean that they themselves are not different.

Comment: Hmmm.... well wait, there is no difference when the two expressions are in conditionals. The difference only arises when they are taken out of the conditional no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They just **differ** on what they return **if there is a match**. If there is no match, both return `nil`.

`~=` returns the numerical index of the character in the string where the match started 
`.match` returns an instance of the class `MatchData`

Comment: I tried reading about this MatchData class. Why are they all in the format #<MatchData "i">? I tried reading the docs but I don't get it still...

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.

Expanding on Nobita's answer, `match` is less efficient if you want to just check to see if a string matches a regexp (like in your case). In that case, you should use `=~`. See the answer to ["Fastest way to check if a string matches or not a regexp in ruby?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888418/1849664), which contains these benchmarks:

```
require 'benchmark'

"test123" =~ /1/
=> 4
Benchmark.measure{ 1000000.times { "test123" =~ /1/ } }
=>   0.610000   0.000000   0.610000 (  0.578133)

...

irb(main):019:0> "test123".match(/1/)
=> #<MatchData "1">
Benchmark.measure{ 1000000.times { "test123".match(/1/) } }
=>   1.703000   0.000000   1.703000 (  1.578146)
```

So, in this case, `=~` is a little less than three times faster than `match`

Comment: I ran a benchmark on the two expressions you tested and also for `"test123"[/1/]` (which returns `1`). For what it's worth, the "total" result for the latter, after adjusting to make it comparable to your results, was about 0.766 seconds.